# Given two NxD matrix, produce NxDxD matrix in more efficient way of implementing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two matrix `A` with shape `(N,D)` and `B` with shape `(N,D)`
for each row of A[i] and B[i] (both D dimension vector), I'm constructing a DxD matrix by matrix multiplication. At end, I would have NxDxD tensor

right now; my code is not efficient and requires a loop; is there any fast way of doing this?

```
result = tf.zeros((1,D,D))
for i in range(N):
    x = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(A[i], (-1, 1)), tf.reshape(B[i], (1, -1)))
    y = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(B[i], (-1, 1)), tf.reshape(A[i], (1, -1)))
    z = tf.reshape(x-y,[1,D,D])
    result  = tf.concat((result,z),axis=0)
result = result[1:,:,:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, your `x` or `y` operation is actually a matrix multiplies `N` of matrices `Dx1` and `N` of matrices `1xD`, and each pair will give you an `DxD` matrix. So you can do it:

```
# (N,D,D) = (N,D,1) X (N,1,D)
x_tensor = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(A,-1),tf.expand_dims(B,1)) 
y_tensor = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(B,-1),tf.expand_dims(A,1))
```

An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N,D = 4,3
A = tf.random_normal(shape=(N,D),mean=1,stddev=2,seed=0)
B = tf.random_normal(shape=(N,D),mean=2,stddev=3,seed=1)

x_tensor = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(A,-1),tf.expand_dims(B,1))
y_tensor = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(B,-1),tf.expand_dims(A,1))
result_tensor = x_tensor-y_tensor

result = tf.zeros((1,D,D))
for i in range(N):
    x = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(A[i], (-1, 1)), tf.reshape(B[i], (1, -1)))
    y = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(B[i], (-1, 1)), tf.reshape(A[i], (1, -1)))
    z = tf.reshape(x-y,[1,D,D])
    result  = tf.concat((result,z),axis=0)
result = result[1:,:,:]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result_tensor ,result = sess.run([result_tensor,result])
    print('tensor:\n',result_tensor)
    print('loop:\n',result)

#print
tensor:
 [[[  0.          3.5620503   1.0253274]
  [ -3.5620503   0.          2.7767086]
  [ -1.0253274  -2.7767086   0.       ]]

 [[  0.        -15.686951   17.729378 ]
  [ 15.686951    0.        -18.756174 ]
  [-17.729378   18.756174    0.       ]]

 [[  0.         -6.8652487   3.215055 ]
  [  6.8652487   0.         -4.023854 ]
  [ -3.215055    4.023854    0.       ]]

 [[  0.         -3.4384773  -1.8167171]
  [  3.4384773   0.         -1.6330992]
  [  1.8167171   1.6330992   0.       ]]]
loop:
 [[[  0.          3.5620503   1.0253274]
  [ -3.5620503   0.          2.7767086]
  [ -1.0253274  -2.7767086   0.       ]]

 [[  0.        -15.686951   17.729378 ]
  [ 15.686951    0.        -18.756174 ]
  [-17.729378   18.756174    0.       ]]

 [[  0.         -6.8652487   3.215055 ]
  [  6.8652487   0.         -4.023854 ]
  [ -3.215055    4.023854    0.       ]]

 [[  0.         -3.4384773  -1.8167171]
  [  3.4384773   0.         -1.6330992]
  [  1.8167171   1.6330992   0.       ]]]
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is very neat !